# 3rd level child on breadcrumbs in woocommerce not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have here a code that works fine except for the woocommerce product page

for example:

```
Home > category1 > category2 > category3
```

but when I go to the product page it shows only like this

```
Home > category1 > product
```

I need it to show in the product page

```
Home > category1 > category2 > category3 > product
```

I think this is where to modify the code 
( if ( get_post_type() == 'product' ) {} )

Here is the code below:

```
function limelight_breadcrumbs()
{
global $post, $wp_query;
if ( ! $home ) $home = __( 'Home', 'limelight' );
$home_link = home_url();
$delimiter = ' &raquo; ';
$currentBefore = '<span class="current">';
$currentAfter = '</span>';
$wrap_before = ' <nav id="breadcrumbs">';
$wrap_after = '</nav> ';

if ( get_option('woocommerce_prepend_shop_page_to_urls') == "yes" && woocommerce_get_page_id( 'shop' ) &&   get_option( 'page_on_front' ) !== woocommerce_get_page_id( 'shop' ) )
$prepend = '<a href="' . get_permalink( woocommerce_get_page_id('shop') ) . '">' . get_the_title( woocommerce_get_page_id('shop') ) . '</a> ' . $delimiter;
else $prepend = '';

if ( ( ! is_front_page() && ! ( is_post_type_archive() && get_option( 'page_on_front' ) == woocommerce_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ) ) || is_paged() ) {

    echo $wrap_before . '<a class="home" href="' . $home_link . '">' . $home . '</a> ' . $delimiter ;

    if ( is_category() ) {

        $cat_obj = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
        $this_category = get_category( $cat_obj->term_id );

        if ( $this_category->parent != 0 ) {
            $parent_category = get_category( $this_category->parent );
            echo get_category_parents($parent_category, TRUE, $delimiter );
        }

        echo $currentBefore . single_cat_title( '', false ) . $currentAfter;


    } elseif ( is_home() ) {

        echo $currentBefore . 'Blog' . $currentAfter;


    } elseif ( is_tax('product_cat') ) {

        echo $prepend;
        $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );

        $parents = array();
        $parent = $term->parent;
        while ( $parent ) {
            $parents[] = $parent;
            $new_parent = get_term_by( 'id', $parent, get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
            $parent = $new_parent->parent;
        }

        if ( ! empty( $parents ) ) {
            $parents = array_reverse( $parents );
            foreach ( $parents as $parent ) {
                $item = get_term_by( 'id', $parent, get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ));
                echo '<a href="' . get_term_link( $item->slug, 'product_cat' ) . '">' . $item->name . '</a>' . $delimiter;
            }
        }

        $queried_object = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
        echo $currentBefore . $queried_object->name . $currentAfter;

    } elseif ( is_tax('product_tag') ) {

        $queried_object = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
        echo $prepend . $currentBefore . __('Products tagged &ldquo;', 'limelight') . $queried_object->name . '&rdquo;' . $currentAfter;

    } elseif ( is_search() ) {

        echo $currentBefore . __( 'Search results for &ldquo;', 'limelight' ) . get_search_query() . '&rdquo;' . $currentAfter;

    } elseif ( is_day() ) {

        echo '<a href="' . get_year_link(get_the_time('Y')) . '">' . get_the_time('Y') . '</a>' . $delimiter;
        echo '<a href="' . get_month_link(get_the_time('Y'),get_the_time('m')) . '">' . get_the_time('F') . '</a>' . $delimiter;
        echo $currentBefore . get_the_time('d') . $currentAfter;

    } elseif ( is_month() ) {

        echo '<a href="' . get_year_link(get_the_time('Y')) . '">' . get_the_time('Y') . '</a>' . $delimiter;
        echo $currentBefore . get_the_time('F') . $currentAfter;

    } elseif ( is_year() ) {

        echo $currentBefore . get_the_time('Y') . $currentAfter;

    } elseif ( is_post_type_archive('product') && get_option('page_on_front') !== woocommerce_get_page_id('shop') ) {

        $_name = woocommerce_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ? get_the_title( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ) : ucwords( get_option( 'woocommerce_shop_slug' ) );

        if ( is_paged() ) {

            echo $currentBefore . '<a href="' . get_post_type_archive_link('product') . '">' . $_name . '</a>' . $currentAfter;

        } else {

            echo $currentBefore . $_name . $currentAfter;

        }

    } elseif ( is_single() && !is_attachment() ) { // *****************************************************************************************************************

        if ( get_post_type() == 'product' ) {

            echo $prepend;

            if ( $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' ) ) {
                $term = current( $terms );
                $parents = array();
                $parent = $term->parent;

                while ( $parent ) {
                    $parents[] = $parent;
                    $new_parent = get_term_by( 'id', $parent, 'product_cat' );
                    $parent = $new_parent->parent;
                }

                if ( ! empty( $parents ) ) {
                    $parents = array_reverse($parents);
                    foreach ( $parents as $parent ) {
                        $item = get_term_by( 'id', $parent, 'product_cat');
                        echo '<a href="' . get_term_link( $item->slug, 'product_cat' ) . '">' . $item->name . '</a>' . $delimiter;
                    }
                }

                echo '<a href="' . get_term_link( $term->slug, 'product_cat' ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>' . $delimiter;

            }



            echo $currentBefore . get_the_title();

        } elseif ( get_post_type() != 'post' ) {

            $post_type = get_post_type_object( get_post_type() );
            $slug = $post_type->rewrite;
                echo $currentBefore . '<a href="' . get_post_type_archive_link( get_post_type() ) . '">' . $post_type->labels->singular_name . '</a>' . $currentAfter . $delimiter;
            echo $currentBefore . get_the_title() . $currentAfter;

        } else {

            $cat = current( get_the_category() );
            echo '<a href="http://localhost/optikinetics/blog/">BLOG</a>' .$delimiter;
            echo $currentBefore . get_the_title() . $currentAfter;

        }

    } elseif ( is_404() ) {

        echo $currentBefore . __( 'Error 404', 'limelight' ) . $currentAfter;

    } elseif ( ! is_single() && ! is_page() && get_post_type() != 'post' ) {

        $post_type = get_post_type_object( get_post_type() );

        if ( $post_type )
            echo $currentBefore . $post_type->labels->singular_name . $currentAfter;

    } elseif ( is_attachment() ) {

        $parent = get_post( $post->post_parent );
        $cat = get_the_category( $parent->ID );
        $cat = $cat[0];
        echo get_category_parents( $cat, true, '' . $delimiter );
        echo $currentBefore . '<a href="' . get_permalink( $parent ) . '">' . $parent->post_title . '</a>' . $currentAfter . $delimiter;
        echo $currentBefore . get_the_title() . $currentAfter;

    } elseif ( is_page() && !$post->post_parent ) {

        echo $currentBefore . get_the_title() . $currentAfter;

    } elseif ( is_page() && $post->post_parent ) {

        $parent_id  = $post->post_parent;
        $breadcrumbs = array();

        while ( $parent_id ) {
            $page = get_page( $parent_id );
            $breadcrumbs[] = '<a href="' . get_permalink($page->ID) . '">' . get_the_title( $page->ID ) . '</a>';
            $parent_id  = $page->post_parent;
        }

        $breadcrumbs = array_reverse( $breadcrumbs );

        foreach ( $breadcrumbs as $crumb )
            echo $crumb . '' . $delimiter;

        echo $currentBefore . get_the_title() . $currentAfter;

    } elseif ( is_tag() ) {

            echo $currentBefore . __( 'Posts tagged &ldquo;', 'limelight' ) . single_tag_title('', false) . '&rdquo;' . $currentAfter;

    } elseif ( is_author() ) {
                global $author;
        $userdata = get_userdata($author);
        echo $currentBefore . __( 'Author:', 'limelight' ) . ' ' . $userdata->display_name . $currentAfter;

    }

    if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) )
        echo ' (' . __( 'Page', 'limelight' ) . ' ' . get_query_var( 'paged' ) . ')';

    echo $wrap_after;

}
}
```

I can't seem to do anything on this and I don't know how.

Answer (score 2):

solved it by inserting pieces of code

```
    $taxonomy = 'product_cat'; //change to your taxonomy name

    // get the term IDs assigned to post.
    $post_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
    // separator between links
    $separator = $delimiter;

    if ( !empty( $post_terms ) && !is_wp_error( $post_terms ) ) {

        $term_ids = implode( ',' , $post_terms );
    $terms = wp_list_categories( 'title_li=&style=none&echo=0&taxonomy=' . $taxonomy . '&include=' . $term_ids );
    $terms = rtrim( trim(  str_replace( '<br />',  $separator, $terms ) ), $separator );

    // display post categories
    echo  $terms . $delimiter;
    }
```

so this will show all the categories related to the product, hope i am right... but works fine